# How do I draw a circle with dots on corel draw?

Tags: shapes, corel-draw

[image: How do I create any of the basic shapes with dots on Corel draw]

If you look at the design closely, you would see some basic shapes with dotted points. How do I create it on Corel?

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods, but I prefer PowerClip. It is one of the most useful tools.

1. Make one circle. Duplicate it and move it to the desired spacing (I prefer using the keypad)

If you press just after that, press Ctrl+D again new circles will appear at the exact same distance.

2. Select the row of circles, you can group them and make the same... Ctrl+D and duplicate them as new rows.
3. Select the pattern Menu>Object>PowerClip and put them inside your shape.

Answer (score 0):

In CorelDraw it's called a *full color pattern*.

1. Draw a filled circle (your dot) that will be your pattern.
2. Click `Tools  > Create > Pattern fill` and select **Full color**.
3. Select the image or area of the image that you want to use in the pattern.
4. Select your object and apply the pattern, you can adjust spacing / size using the **Interactive fill** tool.

Comment: In OPs defense, I did google this and searched through several posts that were not useful and came across this. I have Corel2019 and cannot locate your directions either. Tools>Create>PatternFill is not an option.

Comment: Well, the tool is there at least on my 2017 version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUktl.png

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a pattern of dots and powerclip it inside any object.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Please explain better what you mean, for example by adding one or more screenshots ...

Answer (score -1):

Please check out the tutorial below and see how easy it is to draw circle with dot:

1. Generates dots in linear form using the shape tools
2. duplicate the linear dots horizonatally
3. draw a circle and power clip the linear shapes into it.

I made a [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/sl8Li_AyoUE) of your case.